# Stata data manipulation

Tags: sas, stata, data-modeling, data-manipulation

Let us say my data set is

```
t id b c z
1 1  0 1 1
2 1  1 1 0
3 1  0 1 1
4 1  0 1 1
1 2  0 1 1
1 2  1 1 1
```

I want to create a dummy variable `Dum1` where `Dum1`= 1 if variable `z` takes value of 1 within the next two periods after observing `b` =1 for each `id`.

For example, for `id`=1, `b`=1 at `t`=2 and since for `id`=1 `z`=1 at `t`=3 and `t`=4 the dummy should take a value of one.

If this can be done in SAS, that is also fine.

Comment: I didn't downvote this, but downvotes usually mean "you didn't show us your code; this is not really intended as a site where people write your code for you, even though that sometimes happens".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tsset id t 
gen dum = b == 1 & (F.z == 1 | F2.z == 1)
```

or

```
gen dum = b == 1 & inlist(1, F.z, F2.z)
```

So this is a Stata translation after setting up the data as panel data with a panel and time variable. The indicator (I advise against the term "dummy", often misunderstood as offensive) is

1 if and only if the present value of `b` is 1 and either the next value or the next-but-one value of `z` is 1

0 otherwise

EDIT: If "within the next two time periods" means "both" not "either" then the `inlist()` solution is invalid and the `|` should be `&`, as in @Maarten Buis's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do this in Stata:

```
// make some example data
clear
input ///
t id b c z
1 1  0 1 1
2 1  1 1 0
3 1  0 1 1
4 1  0 1 1
1 2  0 1 1
2 2  1 1 1
end

// start making the variable
tsset id t
gen byte dum1 = ///
 ( ( b == 1 ) & ( F1.z == 1 ) & ( F2.z == 1 ) )
```

I created the indicator variable (a term I prefer over dummy variable) by feeding it a logical statement, which Stata evaluates as 1 if "true" and 0 if "false". For more on that see [here](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/true-and-false/).

I used the [time series operators](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?tsvarlist) `F1.` and `F2.` to get at the values in the next two periods.

Comment: The `by:` prefix is redundant given `tsset`. (Onlookers should be assured that any rivalry here is entirely friendly.)

Comment: This is a different interpretation of "within the next two periods". On second reading it is likely to be what the OP wants.